# Использование типов java в kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Есть такой код на Kotlin:

`val collection: java.util.Collection<String> = java.util.ArrayList<String>()`

почему он компилируется с ошибкой:
`type mismatch: inferred type is ArrayList<String> but Collection<String> was expected`. Вероятно это нормальное поведение, но не могу понять почему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В иерархии типов Kotlin типы `java.util.Collection`, `java.util.List` и прочие интерфейсы коллекций стандартной библиотеки Java заменяются на аналоги из [`kotlin.collections.*`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html), импортированные по умолчанию, например [`List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html) -- это так называемые [отображённые типы (mapped types)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types).

При этом каждый интерфейс коллекции из стандартной библиотеки Java отображается в два типа -- read-only-интерфейс и интерфейс изменяемой коллекции: 
`java.util.List` → `List` (не содержит функций для изменения списка) и `MutableList`.

Из-за этого при проверке типов компилятором Kotlin `ArrayList` не является `java.util.List` или `java.util.Collection` (отсюда и ошибка), вместо этого в его иерархии типов есть `kotlin.collections.List`, `kotlin.collections.Collection`.

IntelliJ IDEA выдаёт предупреждение о том, что интерфейсы коллекций из `java.util.*` не должны использоваться в коде на Kotlin.

---

Самый простой способ исправить ошибку -- заменить интерфейсы из `java.util.*` на соответствующие интерфейсы из `kotlin.collections.*`:

```
val collection: Collection<String> = ArrayList<String>()
```

или, соответственно,

```
val collection: MutableCollection<String> = ArrayList<String>()
```

---

См. также [похожий вопрос на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40549530/2196460).